# Recursive in Merge Sort

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, mergesort

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {20,4,7,6,1,3,9,5};
    mergeSort(numbers);
}
private static void mergeSort(int[] inputArray) {
    int inputLength = inputArray.length;
    System.out.println(inputLength);

    if (inputLength < 2)
        return;


    int midIndex = inputLength / 2;

    int[] leftHalf = new int[midIndex];
    int[] rightHalf = new int[inputLength - midIndex];

    for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i++) {
        leftHalf[i] = inputArray[i];

    }
    for (int i = midIndex; i < inputLength; i++) {
        rightHalf[i - midIndex] = inputArray[i];

    }

    mergeSort(leftHalf);
    mergeSort(rightHalf);
    merge(inputArray, leftHalf, rightHalf);

}
private static void merge(int[] inputArray, int[] leftHalf, int[] rightHalf) {
    int leftSize = leftHalf.length;
    int rightSize = rightHalf.length;

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
        if (leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[i]) {
            inputArray[k] = leftHalf[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            inputArray[k] = rightHalf[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < leftSize) { //eğer karşılaştırılmayan bir tane kalırsa diye yapılıyor yani 
        inputArray[k] = leftHalf[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < rightSize) {
        inputArray[k] = rightHalf[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

}
```

In the `mergeSort` part if `inputLength < 2` part of the code, we return when the length is less than 2. And last time the `inputLength` was 1, it becomes 2 and returns to the array `[20,4]`.

This did not make sense to me logically. How does it get back to `[20,4]` when last we had `[20]` left?

Comment: `[20]` and `[4]` should be merged (by your `merge` method) to `[4,20]`. Debug your code, I cannot spot any obvious errors.

Comment: There is no error in the code. I do not understand the logic of the code,the  return part. @f1sh

Comment: Mergesort is based on a very simple principle: an array with the length of 0 or 1 is considered sorted (because how can it not be?). Thus, `if (inputLength < 2)`, you don't need to sort anything and you can just `return`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "And last time the inputLength was 1, it becomes 2 and returns to the array [20,4]".

Answer (score 0):

first of all the code you have shared is flawed in the merge function part, you can find the proper code for Merge sort online, you can refer to
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-merge-sort/

Now for understanding merge sort you have to understand the concept of stack (Last in First out) & recursion. In recursion the lines after the recursive call wait till the recursive call to the function has not executed completely. So in case of the

1st call Merge sort the length of the array is n and waiting for the complete execution of mergeSort(leftHalf) and mergeSort(rightHalf) both of size (n/2).

now for both the mergeSort(leftHalf) and mergeSort(rightHalf)
there will be sub left part and sub right part and this will continue till the size of the array becomes <2 and the remaining part will wait.

and after the successful execution of the smallest part it will return to the previous part from where this part was called. By this eventually this will return to the place where the function was called first.

And in case of your code both the smaller arrays are merged into the larger array so the data of the left and right sub array aren't lost.